# Regex extract field from complex SQL SELECT in C#

Tags: c#, sql, regex, subquery, match

I'm looking for a regex (I think it's the best way to do it) that will extract field from a complex SQL SELECT Query.

```
select A.field1, A.field2, (B.field1 + ', ' +  B.field2), (SELECT C.field1 FROM C_table AS C WHERE C.Id = A.Id) from A_table as A join B_Table as B ON B.AId = A.Id
```

Or something crazy like that.

The output[] should be:

- A.field1
- A.field2
- (B.field1 + ', ' +  B.field2)
- (SELECT C.field1 FROM C_table AS C WHERE C.Id = A.Id)

I've already done a code to retreive fields beetween SELECT and FROM

```
A.field1, A.field2, (B.field1 + ', ' +  B.field2), (SELECT C.field1 FROM C_table AS C WHERE C.Id = A.Id)
```

So it might be possible to divide at each comma, except those in parentheses...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the second string with the regex `, (?![^\(]*?\))` - split on any comma followed by a space where the next closing parenthesis doesn't precede the next opening parenthesis (if any).

```
string[] output = Regex.Split(select_clause, ", (?![^\(]*?\))");
```

where **select_clause** is the string you extracted from between **SELECT** and **FROM**

Comment: Thanks for this answer -- Is there a way to keep the ")" ? And, if I'm understanding, I'll have to put a space before the comma I want to split and no space before the ones in parentheses... Is there a better way to divide all commas except those in parentheses ?

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty. I fixed the regex to meet your criteria - split on a comma *followed* by a space, but not inside parenthesis. The negative look-ahead verifies that the next closing parenthesis, if any, doesn't come before the next opening parenthesis. This will keep the parentheses. Everything except the delimiters (commans not within parentheses) is kept.

Comment: Since you're new to SO, I just want to point out that you can also upvote answers you accept (by clicking the up arrow above the number to the left of the answer), and generally should unless for some reason you feel that the answer was particularly weak even though you accepted. You can also upvote answers you didn't accept that if you feel that they contributed additional useful and relevant information that helped you with the issue you wanted to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to do what you want

```
/\([^\(]*\)|([\w_]+\.)*[\w_]*/
```

It matches for an opening parens followed by anything beside a closing parens, **or** multiple identifiers (`\w_`) followed by dots. It needs to be adjusted if you need to support more exotic table identifiers like `[Fancy identifier with spaces and brackets].Table.Field1`, but it should work in the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

this will work using capture groups.

(?<=select).*?(?=,)|,.*?(?=,)|(.*?)

this should get anything after select until the end of the string that is between 2 commas(,) and anything between open and closing parenthese. this will work for .net regex which i assume you are using with your c# code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's a valid query already:

```
([^'",]+|(["'])((?!\2).|\\\2)*\2)+
```

That will work for MySQL as long as you aren't using any sets, but not TSQL at all.  It works in two parts:

```
[^'",]+  Any number of characters that are not ', ", or  a comma.
```

or

```
(["'])((?!\2).|\\\2)*\2  A string. (delimited by double or single quotes).
```

If you include sets, you're turning it into a non-regular language, because you have to count parenthetical depth.